# How can i send a post request using vue to django without getting a 403 error?

Tags: django, vue.js, django-csrf

Im trying to send information using a post request of Vue, but every time i try i get an error 403 58 
my django service is ok , i think that the problem is for the csrf token but i dont know how to send it with vue

```js
var vue = new Vue({
    el:"#app",
    data: {
     nombre:"",
        apellido:"",
        password:""

    },

    methods:{
        enviar:function () {
            data = {
                "nombre":this.nombre,
                "apelldio":this.apelldio,
                "password":this.password
            };
            this.$http.post("http://localhost:8000/usuarios\\",data).then(function (data, status, request) {
                if(status ==200){
                    console.log(data);
                }
            },function () {
                console.log("Error");
            });


        }

    }

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://bootswatch.com/4/flatly/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
<h1>Insertar un nuevo usuario </h1>
<table id = "app">

        <tr><td>Nombre:</td><td><input type="texte" class="form-control" v-model="nombre"></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Apellido:</td><td><input type="texte" class="form-control" v-model = "apellido"></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Password:</td><td><input type="texte" class="form-control" v-model="password"></td></tr>
    <tr> <td> <button type="button" id = "enviar" class="btn btn-info" @click="enviar">Enviar</button></td></tr>

</table>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue-resource/0.1.13/vue-resource.min.js"></script>
 {% csrf_token %}
 <!-- here goes the scripts of vue and vue resource!>
```

Comment: this example tutorial may help you with passing [`csrf-token`](https://impythonist.wordpress.com/2015/06/16/django-with-ajax-a-modern-client-server-communication-practise/) along with request

Comment: So, have you found a solution, did one of the answers helped you with it? Give us a feedback so we keep the help ;D

Answer (score 0):

You could use a method that involves fetching the csrf token with javascript and then passing it to the POST request as a header as mentioned [here  in Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/csrf/#setting-the-token-on-the-ajax-request). In that link there is also examples about fetching the csrf token value.

Also, if the endpoint does not require this kind of protection you can disable it like in [this example](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/csrf/#django.views.decorators.csrf.csrf_exempt).

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
{% csrf_token %}
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue-resource/0.1.13/vue-resource.min.js"></script>

<script>
    var csrf = document.querySelector('[name="csrfmiddlewaretoken"]').value;

    Vue.http.interceptors.push(function (request, next) {
        request.headers['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] = csrf;
        next();
    });

    // Or maybe
    Vue.http.headers.common['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] = csrf;
</script>
```

You can also use it like this, for example:

```
<script>
    var csrf = '{{ csrf_token }}';

    Vue.http.headers.common['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] = csrf;
    // Or other way
    // Vue.http.interceptors.push(...);
</script>
```

---

*Note: I'm no `django` developer but gave you the basic idea, so check the [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/csrf/#setting-the-token-on-the-ajax-request) for more info.*